# Algorithm to find smallest ellipse containing p% of points in 2D plane?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, geometry

This question is the same one I want answered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810092/how-to-find-the-smallest-ellipse-covering-a-given-fraction-of-a-set-of-points-in

Except I need to either get the algorithm as plain old math, or possibly MATLAB without any special toolboxes.  The above question was answered using tools from R, which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: I think this might be an unsolved problem.  The code you link to is *ad hoc* and unsupported by any assessment of its performance or correctness, and therefore it shouldn't be relied on without extensive testing and analysis. Do you need the absolute best solution or will a decent approximation be ok; and if so, how close should the approximation be?

Comment: Decent approximation is fine for my purposes.  Not sure how to define that except to say that it shouldn't fail badly (as opposed to being slightly off numerically).  I have my own ad-hoc approach, but it is subject to falling into local maxima that are far from the correct answer in some obvious cases.

Comment: You can find ideas from the literature of robust covar matrix estimation. Look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/381194/numerically-distinguish-between-real-correlation-and-artifact/381253#381253)  where there are use examples (with R), and look up the doc for the used R functions for references.